# Playing different sounds on different buttons using switch statements not working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

When I try to play a different sound on different buttons it doesn't work with switch statements. I tried the same thing if "if-else" statements worked. Please can somebody assist me with what I am doing wrong with the switch statements?

```
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {
    
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    
        var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    
        switch (buttonInnerHTML) {
            case "w":
                var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
                tom1.play();
                break;
    
            case "a":
                var tom2 = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
                tom2.play();
                break;
    
            case "s":
                var tom3 = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
                tom3.play();
                break;
    
            case "d":
                var tom3 = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
                tom4.play();
                break;
    
            case "j":
                var snare = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
                snare.play();
                break;
    
            case "k":
                var crash = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
                crash.play();
                break;
    
            case "l":
                var kick = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
                kick.play();
                break;
    
            default:
                console.log('buttonInnerHTML');
        }
    
    });

}
```

Comment: Try changing `i = 0;` to `let i = 0;`. You could do what you are trying to do without using a loop. To get rid of the loop, add the click listener on the common parent element of all the elements with the `drum` class. To get the `buttonInnerHTML`, you can use the `event` parameter passed to the callback function of the `addEventListener`: `const buttonInnerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;` After this, you need the `switch` statement to determine which sound to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line

document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener('click', () => {

solved it by changing it to

document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

Comment: That's because there's no `this` unless you use `function()`.